# Plugin not Working with FileBeat in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

> Blockquote2018-05-31T16:51:02.494+0530
>   ERROR   fileset/factory.go:93   Error loading pipeline: Error loading pipeline for fileset apache2/access: This module requires the following Elasticsearch plugins: ingest-user-agent, ingest-geoip. You can install them by running the following commands on all the Elasticsearch nodes:
>       sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-user-agent
>       sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-geoip

Have Installed both the Plugins as administrator but on running the Filebeat getting this error, on retrying to install it shows plugin already exist

Here is the Link to Entire Log File [Terminal Error in File Beat](https://gist.github.com/harshityadav95/70a0142bb92e03262b02ab1866c8868e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it on **all** your nodes in the cluster.

You can look here for more details.

[git hub reference](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-core)